# How to access/read packages in Azure Artifact with PAT token

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Is there a way I can connect my Visual studio to Azure Artifact source feed with PAT token? I need to add packages to my project

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Create a nuget.config file in the root of your project (where sln is). I used the Package Manager Console to run the command "dotnet new nugetconfig"

In the nuget.exe file, I replaced content with following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="FeedName" value="artifact URL" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"/>
  </packageSources>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <FeedName>
      <add key="Username" value="User" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%PATTokenEnvrionmentVariable%" />
    </FeedNamet>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Then I ran "dotnet restore" and restarted Visual studio